# Split toolbar title in multiple lines on small screens

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am using v-toolbar in my vue app. I am able to figure out how I can split title to multiple lines on small screens like:

```
Section
  One
Organisation
```

Right now it looks like Secti.... on small screens. Please help me resolve this issue.

```
<v-toolbar dense fixed scroll-off-screen>
 <v-layout row wrap>
   <v-flex xs4 md4>
     <v-toolbar-title><a>Section One Organisation</a></v-toolbar-title>
   </v-flex>
   <v-flex xs4 md4>
     <v-toolbar-title><a>Section Two Contact</a></v-toolbar-title>
   </v-flex>
   <v-flex xs4 md4>
     <v-toolbar-title><a>Section Three Location</a></v-toolbar-title>
   </v-flex>
 </v-layout>
</v-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to display shorter title depending of screen size. Rendering should display only parts who are xs for small screen.

You could also a custom css class only for xs4 v-flex.

Hope that's help.

```
<v-toolbar dense fixed scroll-off-screen>
  <v-layout row wrap>

    <!-- first section - small + medium + large screen -->
    <v-flex md4>
      <v-toolbar-title><a>Section One Organisation</a></v-toolbar-title>
    </v-flex>
    <!-- first section - extra small screen -->
    <v-flex xs4>
      <v-toolbar-title><a>Organisation</a></v-toolbar-title>
    </v-flex>

    <!-- second section -->
    <v-flex md4 class="landing-page-section">
      <v-toolbar-title><a>Section Two Contact</a></v-toolbar-title>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex xs4 class="landing-page-section">
      <v-toolbar-title><a>Contact</a></v-toolbar-title>
    </v-flex>

    <!-- third section -->
    <v-flex md4 class="landing-page-section">
      <v-toolbar-title><a>Section Three Location</a></v-toolbar-title>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex xs4 class="landing-page-section">
      <v-toolbar-title><a>Location</a></v-toolbar-title>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</v-toolbar>
```

Comment: Actually I want the entire text rather than just one single word.

Section 
   One
Organisation

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify provide a helper class for this case: `class="text-break"`.

Comment: I tried some like this but it didnt work.
<v-toolbar-title class="text-break"><a>Section One Organisation</a></v-toolbar-title>

Comment: Did you defined css class text-break? I don't think that's come by default with Vue.js

Comment: Maybe `.text-wrap {white-space: normal;}` and set it to your v-flex

Comment: @Camille from the layout, provided by the OP, it is evident that he uses the Vuetify framework, and Vuetify provides this helper class.  I don't know any css classes that comes by default with Vuejs...